# Парсинг строки на c# через :

Tags: c#, .net, парсер

Есть строка вида `"1:String1:2:2:3:String3:4:String4"`
Эту строку нужно распарсить в

```
string 1 = String1
int 2 = 2
string 3 = String3
string 4 = String4
```

Как это можно реализовать на c#?

UPD: количество и тип каждого значения заранее известен

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Пока не ясно, что за представление данных. Ключевое слово `var` не может участвовать как принимающий тип для данных, потому что это фишка компилятора и в рантайме ее использовать не возможно.

Comment: непонятно как это сделать, пробовал через цикл for, но непонятно как разделить значения через один

Comment: в коде не var, а string и int, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Как можно числу, да еще и с типом `string` присваивать переменную?

Comment: @ГеннадийП никак, это не код, как я понял, а просто представление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для пар ключ-значение можно использовать словарь

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    string text = "1:String1:2:2:3:String3:4:String4";
    string[] values = text.Split(':');
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i += 2)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(values[i], out int index))
            dictionary.Add(index, values[i + 1]);
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in dictionary)
    {
        bool isInt = int.TryParse(pair.Value, out _);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} = {2}", isInt ? "int" : "string", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
string 1 = String1
int 2 = 2
string 3 = String3
string 4 = String4
```